# How to Display WebcamTexture as Full Screen on Android Portrait Mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am trying to display full screen Webcamtexture on android Portrait mode.
but when i am building and testing it on my device its rotated and videoRotationAngle is 90

I am using RawImage as a texture. I have seen on some post that you have to rotate the transform and get the right angle. But the problem is that if I rotate RawImage UI it will no longer full screen view.

```
  var camImage:UnityEngine.UI.RawImage;
  var baseRotation:Quaternion;
  var webcamTexture:WebCamTexture;
  var rotation:UnityEngine.UI.Text;


function Start () {

         webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(Screen.width,Screen.height);
         camImage.texture=webcamTexture;
         camImage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
         webcamTexture.Play();
         rotation.text= webcamTexture.videoRotationAngle.ToString(); // to check the angle


}
```

Comment: You could get the camera width and height before performing any rotation and use that to stretch the texture to the required dimensions.

I use an orthographic camera, so my code may not apply to your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late reply but may help someone facing similar issues.

If you are using RawImage as a Texture, below code should help you achieve the rendering both in Potrait and Landscape mode.

Just ensure that you set "Aspect Mode" in "Aspect Ratio Fitter" of Raw Image to "Width Controls Height" or "Height Controls Width" (whichever is larger based on orientation)

Code Snippet

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public class DeviceCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage image;
    public AspectRatioFitter imageFitter;

    //set it to either FRONT or BACK
    string myCamera = "BACK";

    // Device cameras
    WebCamDevice frontCameraDevice;
    WebCamDevice backCameraDevice;
    WebCamDevice activeCameraDevice;

    WebCamTexture frontCameraTexture;
    WebCamTexture backCameraTexture;
    WebCamTexture activeCameraTexture;

    // Image rotation
    Vector3 rotationVector = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

    // Image uvRect
    Rect defaultRect = new Rect(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
    Rect fixedRect = new Rect(0f, 1f, 1f, -1f);

    // Image Parent's scale
    Vector3 defaultScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    Vector3 fixedScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);

    void Start()
    {
        // Check for device cameras
        if (WebCamTexture.devices.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("No devices cameras found");
            return;
        }

        // Get the device's cameras and create WebCamTextures with them
        frontCameraDevice = WebCamTexture.devices.Last();
        backCameraDevice = WebCamTexture.devices.First();

        frontCameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(frontCameraDevice.name);
        backCameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(backCameraDevice.name);

        // Set camera filter modes for a smoother looking image
        frontCameraTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
        backCameraTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;

        // Set the camera to use by default
        if (myCamera.Equals("FRONT"))
            SetActiveCamera(frontCameraTexture);
        else if (myCamera.Equals("BACK"))
            SetActiveCamera(backCameraTexture);
        else // default back
            SetActiveCamera(backCameraTexture);
    }

    // Set the device camera to use and start it
    public void SetActiveCamera(WebCamTexture cameraToUse)
    {
        if (activeCameraTexture != null)
        {
            activeCameraTexture.Stop();
        }

        activeCameraTexture = cameraToUse;
        activeCameraDevice = WebCamTexture.devices.FirstOrDefault(device =>
            device.name == cameraToUse.deviceName);

        image.texture = activeCameraTexture;
        image.material.mainTexture = activeCameraTexture;

        activeCameraTexture.Play();
    }

    // Make adjustments to image every frame to be safe, since Unity isn't 
    // guaranteed to report correct data as soon as device camera is started
    void Update()
    {
        // Skip making adjustment for incorrect camera data
        if (activeCameraTexture.width < 100)
        {
            Debug.Log("Still waiting another frame for correct info...");
            return;
        }

        // Rotate image to show correct orientation 
        rotationVector.z = -activeCameraTexture.videoRotationAngle;
        image.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = rotationVector;

        // Set AspectRatioFitter's ratio
        float videoRatio =
            (float)activeCameraTexture.width / (float)activeCameraTexture.height;
        imageFitter.aspectRatio = videoRatio;

        // Unflip if vertically flipped
        image.uvRect =
            activeCameraTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? fixedRect : defaultRect;

    }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Solved it for me on Unity v2019.2.19f1 (iOS)

Comment: Solved it for me on Unity v2019.2.19f1 (Android)

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two options: you could either pick portrait or landscape and block screen rotation, or you could automatically rotate your object and stretch it according to the screen boundaries. See Screen.height and Screen.length for more info.

Comment: my android build is set to portrait mode only.The problem with transform rotation that it will stretched too much and it will not look good.

Comment: If you can't receive the Web cam texture in a different resolution then it can't be fullscreen without distortion or resizing as far as I know.

Comment: when you open camera app in portrait mode you don't see distortion which means that its not hardware limitation. I am looking for something like that . maybe it requires to build plugin for that

Answer (score 0):

`(mCamera.videoRotationAngle + 90) % 360` will rotate the texture properly, then  assign a `localScale` that swaps the height and width of the texture to fix the size.

Answer (score -1):

You need to flip and rotate it. If you something like CameraCaptureKit (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673) you will see there is diffirent ways of achieving what you want. In CameraCaptureKit there is a customized RawImage component that essentailly fiddles with the UV coordinates of the RawImahge instead of roatting it. That way you can rotate the image 90 or 270 and flip it without worring if the phone is running in landscape mode or what ever.

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's an advertisement. It's a $30 paid software being used to solve one of the oldest and most well-known camera issues for any Android app attempting to use a live camera view. The solution is not some revolutionary or proprietary creation by the author.